how come child component has access to styles i.e. id set in app component in react
in app.js i am using layout like this
 <div id={theme}>
        <About />
        <TechStack />
        <Education />
        <Project />
        <Contact />
 </div>

in about.js component , in its css file about.css
#dark .about-section{
    background-color: #38004C;
}

it changes color of about section when {theme} id is dark and theme is from app.js file(parent component). how come we can define #dark in about.css when we have set it in app.css

That's how CSS works. Your rule says "any element that uses the class .about-section anywhere inside the tree that has #dark as starting point", Normal CSS, using classes and stylesheets, gets applied to the document by the browser, not "by React, to individual components" (thankfully. Styling would be a complete disaster if it did)

The about.css file can target the #dark .about-section selector, even though the #dark ID is set in the parent component (App.js), is due to the way CSS selectors work with descendant combinators and the Document Object Model (DOM) hierarchy.
When rendered, your structure might look like this in the DOM:
<div id="dark">
<div class="about-section">
    <!-- About component content -->
</div>
<div class="techstack-section">
    <!-- TechStack component content -->
</div>
<!-- Other components -->


how come we can define #dark in about.css when we have set it in app.css

You can define #dark in about.css and have it apply to elements in your React component tree because CSS operates globally by default and is applied based on how the browser interprets and renders the DOM. Please inspect app in the browser.
